# Laravel Nginx redirect old urls

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have redeveloped a php site using the laravel framework. I now want to redirect the old urls like `/products.php?id_categ=1&id_brand=4&id_products=5` to `/products/product_name`

I have alreay made a route that will accept any url with product.php
`Route::get('products.php','ProductController@oldLinks');`

The function `oldLinks` in `ProductController` finds the product slug based on the id and displays the appropriate product.

This all works in the local environment when I do `php artisan serve` but it will not work in the production server which uses nginx.

How do I get about solving this issue?

Here is the nginx conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name laravel.com www.laravel.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php7.0-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Comment: BTW, Nginx  gives 404

Comment: need more infomation, like nginx error.log or php error log

Comment: Nothing in the error log regarding this issue. Only errors regarding missing images. access log does register the access but thats it.

Comment: Your nginx is probably configured to catch all php files as actual files. Please post your nginx config for this website.

Comment: I have updated the question with the nginx conf file.